# restTemplate.exchange method gives an error when ">" and "<" symbols are present in response

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate

I'm writing a function to POST requests to a few REST APIs.

Here is the code I came up with.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplate")
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public String post(String lambdaApiBasicUri, String pathPostfix, String reqBody) throws Exception {
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(reqBody, createHeaders());  
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(  
            createReqUrl(lambdaApiBasicUri, pathPostfix), 
            HttpMethod.POST, 
            requestEntity, 
            String.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

This works great for all cases except when one particular error message from the API has `<` and `>` symbols in the body. In that case it gives me the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://example.com/abc": Attempted read from closed stream.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:538)
```

I learnt from googling around that this exception is thrown when we try to 'consume' the response more than once. But the problem is I never even get to the part where `responseEntity.getBody();` is called. The error is thrown in restTemplate.exchange() call itself.

I was able to solve the problem by piecing together a `resttempalte.execute()` call instead of `restTemplate.exchange()`. But I want to know why this error is thrown.

Comment: What version of Spring you are using? Maybe try to use the latest version to verify whether it resolved. Because the issue you described sounds like a bug of `RestTemplate` ( can't handle `< >` properly)